# Custom JVP and VJP for higher order functions in JAX

Tags: python, function, higher-order-functions, jax, autodiff

I find custom automatic differentiation capabilities (JVP, VJP) very useful in JAX, but am having a hard time applying it to higher order functions. A minimal example of this sort is as follows: given a higher order function:

```
def parent_func(x):
    def child_func(y):
        return x**2 * y
    return child_func
```

I would like to define custom gradients of `child_func` with respect to x and y. What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradients in JAX are defined with respect to a function’s explicit inputs. Your `child_func` does not take `x` as an explicit input, so you cannot directly differentiate `child_func` with respect to `x`. However, you could do so indirectly by calling it from another function that takes `x`. For example:

```py
def func_to_differentiate(x, y):
  child_func = parent_func(x)
  return child_func(y)

jax.grad(func_to_differentiate, argnums=0)(1.0, 1.0)  # 2.0
```

Then if you wish, you could define standard [custom derivative rules](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Custom_derivative_rules_for_Python_code.html) for `func_to_differentiate`.